# How to enable Firebase Analytics Debugview on Testflight

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, testflight, firebase-analytics

I am unable to view analytics debug view after I install the app through TestFlight into my test phone.

I have passed in argument -FIRDebugEnabled, and have tried -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled but no luck.

-FIRDebugEnabled
-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

If I directly installed the app into my test phone through Xcode, the debug view will be available. But if it's installed through TestFlight, the debug view cannot be seen.

Comment: Any solution ??

Comment: I am also looking for solution. Have you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by injecting special flags into Firebase's local storages. `-FIRDebugEnabled` command line argument is being checked by both: **FirebaseCore** and **FirebaseAnalytics** frameworks. While the former is saving the flag into shared `UserDefaults`, the latter is using `APMUserDefaults` private class, which can be accessed in runtime:

```
if let APMUserDefaults = NSClassFromString("APMUserDefaults") as AnyObject?,
   let userDefaults = APMUserDefaults.perform(#selector(getter: UserDefaults.standard))?.takeUnretainedValue() {
   _ = userDefaults.perform(#selector(NSMutableDictionary.setObject(_:forKey:)),
                            with: true, 
                            with: "/google/measurement/debug_mode")
}
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "/google/firebase/debug_mode")
```

Comment: Nice - this works! You can also trigger this at runtime and then kill and relaunch and it'll be the same as launching with the debug flags.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following code **before** `FirebaseApp.configure()`:

```swift
var newArguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
newArguments.append("-FIRDebugEnabled")
ProcessInfo.processInfo.setValue(newArguments, forKey: "arguments")
```

Then, go to your **target's build settings** and update [**Release's Optimization level**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opgwp.png) to `No Optimization [-Onone]`.

After that, upload to TestFlight. This method works for me!

Answer (score 4):

Add following code at the first line of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of `AppDelegate` file

```
CommandLine.arguments.append(contentsOf: ["-FIRDebugEnabled", "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled"])
```

Comment: how to do it in objective c?

Comment: Did not work for me when tested now.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the previous answers and for React Native users looking for this, if you are using a library like [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config), you can use an env variable to switch this on/off.

Environment variables file example

```
ANALYTICS_DEBUG=true
```

In your AppDelegate.mm, inside the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
  NSString *analyticsDebug = [ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"ANALYTICS_DEBUG"];

  if (analyticsDebug != nil && [analyticsDebug isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    NSProcessInfo *processInfo = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
    NSArray *arguments = [processInfo arguments];
    NSMutableArray *newArguments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arguments];

    [newArguments addObject:@"-FIRDebugEnabled"];
    [newArguments addObject:@"-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled"];

    [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] setValue:[newArguments copy] forKey:@"arguments"];
  }

  // Setup Firebase
  [FIRApp configure];
```

Make sure you setup Firebase after, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: This fix does not look to work anymore. Do you have a new solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an effective solution for 2024 here:

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7648

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: @starball Am I supposed to duplicate my own response on Github instead of just link it ?

Comment: It's ironic that you criticize me for posting a link as a response, while responding with another link. I at least explained what the link contains unlike you
 :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if everything is required here, but this works in Swift with the latest versions. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and before `FirebaseApp.configure()`:

```swift
CommandLine.arguments.append(contentsOf: ["-FIRDebugEnabled", "-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled"])
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "/google/measurement/debug_mode")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "/google/firebase/debug_mode")
```

If it does not work for you, in Info.plist, add the key `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED` to `NO` to make sure that the analytics collection will start only after you set the debug mode, and then call after `FirebaseApp.configure()`:

```swift
Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```